# PHP message: PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Wordpress Site

Warning:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4102\nPHP message: PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4102\nPHP message: PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4102\nPHP message: PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4102\n', referer: mysite
```

Here is line 4101 - 4103 of functions.php

```
function validate_file( $file, $allowed_files = '' ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $file, '..' ) )
        return 1;
```

Comment: You get that message because _strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given_.

Answer (score 1):

This means your first Parameter passed to strpos($file) is not a string, it's an array. Do a 
`var_dump($file)` one line before you call strpos to see what you actually have as value.

If you have the $files array direct from a files form, $file['tmp'] could it be. But easiest way to figure out is a var_dump.